# Check if String is only line breaks

Tags: java, string, line-breaks

I am trying to check if a given String contains only line breaks and no characters. I use this method

```
boolean breaksNoLetters(String msg) {
   if (!msg.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*") && msg.contains("\n")) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

It only does not return false if it contains a line break though.

Comment: By characters you mean letters? So a number with wgite characters will pss right?

Comment: everything will pass except \n

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not test it against this regex?

```
if (msg.matches("[\\n\\r]+")) { }
```

This regular expression will match all the strings that contain one or more characters from the set of `\n` and `\r`.

Answer (score 6):

> I am trying to check if a given String contains only line breaks and no characters.

```
String Path1 = "\n\r";
String Path2 = "foo\nbar";
System.out.println(Path1.matches("[\\n\\r]+"));
System.out.println(Path2.matches("[\\n\\r]+"));
```

`"[\\n\\r]+"` matches one or more new line or carriage return characters. Use also the `\\f` (*form feed*) inside the character class if necessary.

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun for this "\n\r" input , this `System.out.println(Path1.matches("[\n\r]+"));` returns true. Do you know why?

Comment: In regexp, `\n` and `\\n` is the same for most purposes. Other regexp escapes are different because the Java compiler doesn't have direct support for them.

Comment: @AaronDigulla yep, i think so.

Comment: @AvinashRaj `\r` and `\n` works, but if you try `\d` it will be a compilation error since the backslash has to be escaped, but Java already knows what `\n` and `\r` are. If you write `\\n` it's the same as `\n`.

Comment: yep, i know about other escape sequences like `\d,\S,\s` etc. @Aaron clear my doubts. Thank you both..

Answer (score 3):

One way to go would be to replace `\n` with a blank string and check if anything remains:

```
boolean breaksNoLetters(String msg) {
   return !msg.replace("\n", "").isEmpty();
}
```

EDIT:
With Java 8's streams, it's pretty easy to check that all the characters are, in fact, `\n`s:

```
boolean justLineBreaks = msg.chars().allMatch(c -> c == '\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

Impossible, you wrote

> only line breaks and no characters

and line breaks are special character. Step back and think about what problem you want to solve. Is it just to check if a minimum of one single printable character is given? Then trim() the String and check if length() > 0. Else the RegEx above is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to check if a `String` contains **only one** *line break* and no other characters, use the `equals()` method:

```
public boolean isLineBreak(String line) {
    return line.equals(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Another suggest I give you, is to use the `System.getProperty("line.separator")` method in order to get the line separator chars, because it's *platform independent*. For example, *UNIX* uses `\n` and *Windows* `\r\n`. With this method you don't have to care of this.

Java 7 has the `System.lineSeparator()` method, which allows you to do the same as `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Otherwise, if you have to check if a `String` contains **one or more** *line break*, simply use this:

```
public boolean isLineBreak(String line) {
    return line.matches("[\\n\\r]+");
}
```